# Spark Error: Table or view 'users' not found in database 'default';

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I am trying to send an SQL query using spark via JDBC using:

```java
    var s =
        SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[4]")
            .config("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host/service")
            .config("username", "username")
            .config("password", "password")
            .config("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").getOrCreate();

   var x = s.sql("SELECT * FROM USERS"); //Table or view 'users' not found in database 'default';
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong? I dont want to `read` the table or configure the table before hand since I want to send dynamic sql queries to database. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: try putting the database and user name.. for example [database].[dbo].[Users]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the API's incorrectly and at wrong places:-

First create a spark object:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.
                builder().
                master("local").
                appName("SQL- Transformations").
                getOrCreate()
```

Then using this spark object read or write the data which you want:-

For reading the table use below code:-

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

For writing a dataframe into a table use below code:-

```
jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()
```

And If you want to send a query while reading the data through spark jdbc use below code:-

```
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("query", "select c1, c2 from t1") //passing query
    .option("user", "username")
    .option("password", "password")
    .load()
```

Below are couple of restrictions while using **query** option.
1.It is not allowed to specify `dbtable` and `query` options at the same time.
2.It is not allowed to specify `query` and `partitionColumn` options at the same time. When specifying `partitionColumn` option is required, the subquery can be specified using `dbtable` option instead and partition columns can be qualified using the subquery alias provided as part of `dbtable`.

once you have read the data into a datframe register it as temp table and then you can query on it using spark sql

```
jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("select * from df").show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I have just another question, is there a way to process query result (dataset) without loading it entirely to memory? I want to iterate over rows as collection of 1000 for example.

Comment: You can try using fetchsize which determines how many rows to fetch per round trip. This can help performance on JDBC drivers which default to low fetch size (eg. Oracle with 10 rows). This option applies only to reading.   spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("query", "select c1, c2 from t1") //passing query
    .option("user", "username")
    .option("password", "password")
    .option("fetchsize",1000).load()

Comment: This answer mostly quotes Spark documentation from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html). It does not say why error happens and what to do to avoid it.